# How to get a long url from a short url

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, http, bit.ly, short-url

I would like to determine what the long url of a short url is. I have tried using http HEAD requests, but very few of the returned header fields actually contain any data pertaining to the destination/long url.

Is there:
1. Any way to determine the long url?
2. If so, can it be done without downloading the body of the destination?

Thank you

Comment: What's a long URL and what's a short URL? Is http://stackoverflow.com/ long or short? :)

Comment: I assume by short URL he's referring to URL shortening services like tinyurl.com or bit.ly

Comment: I assume he means a URL from a URL shortening service. You should be able to do this by looking at the response headers of a request to the URL without actually beginning to stream the body.

Comment: http://bit.ly/cwz5Jd is an example of a short URL. stackoverflow.com is an example of a long url

Comment: Stefan - that is exactly what I tried

Comment: But what if you want to get a short URL from a long URL? Eg: http://www.freakinghugeurl.com/refer.php?count=4&url=VjFaV2IxVXdNVWhVYTFacFRURndUbFJVUVRCa01XUlhXa1U1YW1KVmJEWldNakUwWVcxS1YyTkljRnBoYXpWeFdrWmFjbVZWT1ZsVmF6Rk9UVVpzTkZZeWVHOVVNREZJVW14b1VGZEdXbkZhVmxKdlRsWlNjbFZyTlU1U1ZHeEdWMnBPYjFSVk1YUmhSRXBoVTBkME5GUlZaRXRPVlRGWVRsZEdXRkpyV1hkV01WcE9aVWROZVZOWWJFOVdlbFpPVmpCYVlVNVdiSEpVV0docFZqQTFNRlF4YUZOVVZsbDNWbXBDV21WcmNIWmFSekZQWkZaV1dWVnRkRmhTV0VJMg==

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a `HEAD` and look for the `Location` header.

```
% telnet bit.ly 80
Trying 168.143.173.13...
Connected to bit.ly.
Escape character is '^]'.
HEAD /cwz5Jd HTTP/1.1
Host: bit.ly

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved
Server: nginx/0.7.42
Date: Fri, 12 Mar 2010 18:37:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: _bit=4b9a89fa-002bd-030af-baa08fa8;domain=.bit.ly;expires=Wed Sep  8 14:37:46 2010;path=/; HttpOnly
Location: http://www.engadget.com/2010/03/12/motorola-milestone-with-android-2-1-hitting-bulgaria-by-march-20/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Length: 404
```

Comment: This ended up to be the most correct answer. The complete answer includes doing a head request as recommended in this answer by calmh. The response containing the location header can be extracted from the "connection willSendRequest...." delegate method, not the didReceiveResponse delegate method.

Comment: HEAD does not always work, but GET generally does. The only caveat with GET is that the connection must be cancelled after url extraction to prevent downloading of the body (as suggested by Seva below)

Comment: JK: You mean `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:`. I thought your comment was wrong until I looked it up and saw the third component of the selector.

Answer (score 6):

Issue an HTTP GET request, don't follow the redirect, analyse the Location header. That's where the target of redirection is.

Specifically in Cocoa, use an asynchronous request with a delegate, handle the didReceiveResponse in the delegate. The first response will be the redirection one. Once you extract the URL in the handler, call [cancel] on the connection.

EDIT: depending on the provider, HEAD instead of GET might or might not work. And if you don't follow the redirect, the response data won't be loaded anyway, so there's no transmission overhead to having a GET.

Answer (score 3):

[LongUrlPlease](http://www.longurlplease.com/docs) offers an API which expands short urls.